# Note-taking application that can sync between Windows, Ubuntu and Android

Tags: windows, linux, android, note-taking

Evernote has been one of the most used note-taking application for me, with it syncing between my Windows PC and my Android device. I usually use the Evernote desktop client on my Windows PC and the Evernote app from Play Store on my Android.

But, since I also manage a PC running on Ubuntu, I have to switch on to my web-browser to access my notes, thus making it unavailable offline. Is there any native app for Ubuntu that can sync with Evernote?

Or, can you suggest a good note-taking application with enough features that has a client for Windows, Ubuntu and Android?

Comment: What kind of notes? Large text notes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note I'm no longer using Evernote, but back in time best option on Ubuntu to manage Evernote was [**Everpad** - git hub page](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad).

[image: Everpad sys-try icon with drop down menu]

Everpad is the closest thing to an official Evernote client for Ubuntu I ever found.

Everpad has **indicator applet** with a drop-down menu of recent notebooks.

On Ubuntu unity desktop, Everpad makes all of your **Evernote notes searchable from the dash** which is just an nice  addition to already good application, and of course client have an unity launcher too.

[image: Evernote notes in dash]

To install Ubuntu 12.04+ users can use ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install everpad
```

An pretty good review of Everpad app you can find [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/everpad-25-released-with-note-sharing.html)

Comment: Judging from its [GitHub graph page](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/graphs), unfortunately the project is not much active now.

Comment: I'm curious - you no longer use evernote, because you found something better? Care to share what that is?

Comment: Nah, I just changed the way I save notes and stuff I need

Answer (score 10):

It's slightly cheating but [Google Keep](https://drive.google.com/keep/) (login required) has a native [Android client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en), as well as the ability to be run, and be launched as its own app.
You very simply need to select it at the apps page on chrome, and create shortcuts to run it without firing up chrome.

[It can also be run offline](http://googledrive.blogspot.sg/2013/05/access-google-keep-with-new-chrome-app.html) - I've tested this to be sure

[image]

The UI is *very* clean, and updates between devices is almost instant while you have an internet connection.

Comment: That looks pretty neat. 

I hadn't used it much till now. But, it will take some time for me to switch from Evernote to Google Keep. So, I will have to go with Everpad for now to get the job done for me.

Comment: Oh absolutely. Moving between services is *hard* and everpad does seem like a good option.

Answer (score 10):

If you're *seriously* invested in evernote, and don't want to switch over, [nevernote/nixnote](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nevernote/) is a FOSS client for linux that will sync with evernote.

You can find a [ppa here to install it on ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~vincent-c/+archive/nevernote). You will need to select `tools -> connect` to add your evernote account, and you do seem to have to trigger sync manually. Other than that, it seems to fit your needs perfectly well.

It caches data locally for offline use so, it should pretty much match all your needs perfectly without leaving the evernote ecosystem.

I'd also add it felt a little sluggish for me - I was running it on an older system with 512 mb of ram I use for testing, so this might be an issue, but their [issue tracker on evernote](https://www.evernote.com/pub/baumgarr/nevernote#b=2dee229e-bc57-4e15-8f8c-acf51030ba6a&st=p&n=8c727a30-91e0-45e5-9e82-c0013aae5982) also suggests that opening too many notebooks may cause issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely [ToDoist](https://en.todoist.com).

ToDoist is a to-do list application, that is available on several platforms - Android, Iphone, there's a windows app, *browser based* app etc. It syncs very well between these.

[image]

It looks like there isn't a specific linux app, but you can just use the browser one, which works very well.

It allows you to set due dates, and arrange tasks into projects.

[image]

You can add notes (which includes files and pictures) to your tasks if you pay for the premium version.

[image]

I highly recommend paying for premium, it only costs about $16 a year from memory, I couldn't find it on their website, it's such a good app that I'd pay for it even without the additional functionality that premium gives.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a [Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) solution, you can investigate [Tomdroid](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy/). It can sync with a server. As far as I know two implementations exist: [Snowy](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Snowy) and [Rainy](https://github.com/Dynalon/Rainy).  I'm not aware of any hosting services offering tomboy sync.

Tomboy seems to run on [Windows](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy/Installing/Windows), so that platform is taken care of. Ubuntu [ships tomboy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tomboy) since ages.  [Tomdroid](https://launchpad.net/tomdroid) seems to be the client for Android.

[image]

[image]